# Anaconda boot with a bonded interface on a tagged vlan

Tags: vlan, bonding, installer-anaconda

I am trying to do a network install of OEL 8 using a custom image. The image works perfectly when the vlan is untagged but I can't get a connection on a tagged vlan. My boot line is (with line feeds added for readability)

```
linuxefi /images/pxeboot/vmlinuz \
inst.repo=https://repo.example.com/kickstart-oel-8/boot \
inst.ks=https://repo.example.com/kickstart-oel-8/ks.cfg \
ip=198.162.100.2::198.162.100.1:24:oel.example.com:bond0:none \
nameserver=198.162.100.100 \
bond=bond0:eno5,eno6:mode=802.3ad,other_options \
vlan=vlan501:bond0 \
rd.plymouth=0 plymouth.enable=0 quiet
```

For systems on an untagged vlan I just remove the `vlan=` option. The system I am installing on was previously running CentOS 7 with the network configured with a tagged vlan and bonded interface so I know the switch port settings are correct as are the physical interface names.

I've looked at a few references both [official](https://docs.centos.org/en-US/centos/install-guide/adminoptions/) and [unofficial](https://leo.leung.xyz/wiki/Red_Hat_kickstart) and played with different formats for the `vlan=` parameter.

The image is based on OEL8u6 minimal iso. The only change I made to the image was to put in custom isolinux and grub configs.

Has anybody gotten a setup like this working? If so, what am I doing wrong? I have 250+ servers to rebuild and I really need the process to be as automated as possible.

EDIT:
After removing `quiet` from the boot line I see these messages

```
8021q: adding VLAN 0 to HW filter on device eno5
8021q: adding VLAN 0 to HW filter on device eno6
Ethernet Channel Bonding Driver: 3.7.1 (April 27, 2011)
8021q: adding VLAN 0 to HW filter on device bond0
8021q: adding VLAN 0 to HW filter on device bond0
nlx5_core 0000:5d:00.0 eno5: Link up
nlx5_core 0000:5d:00.1 eno6: Link up
bond0: Warning: No 802.3ad response from the link partner for any adapters in the bond
bond0: active interface up!
```

I filtered out some other lines that did not add any information. I also had to type these in manually but I don't think any typos crept in.

Answer (score 0):

I did find an answer to the problem thanks to [this](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/25133) article behind the Red Hat semi-paywall. Two changes to the boot line:

```
ip=198.162.100.2::198.162.100.1:32:oel.example.com:bond0.501:none
vlan=bond0.501:bond0
```

Essentially, name the bonded interface with the vlan ID and change the interface to be used to be the bonded name. As is often the case, the answer is simple once it is pointed out to you.

I'll mark this as an accepted answer after the waiting period expires.